# Help with Probability Question: Coin flip

Tags: probability

Joe tosses an unbiased coin continuosly, until, for the first time, the same result is repeated in two consecutive throws (that is, 2 heads in a row or 2 tails in a row).

i)What is the probability that the game ends within the first 3 throws?

ii)Joe decides that he wins if the game ends after an odd number of throws, and he loses if the game ends after an even number of throws. Find the probability that Joe wins the game.

Answer (score 1):

So obviously for the first part, we have that the game could end either in two throws or three throws. If it ends in two throws, the possible choices are that the outcomes are both heads or tails, so this is a probability of $\frac 14+ \frac 14 = \frac12$. If it ends in three throws, the following are the possible outcomes: $$\{THH, HTT\} $$ Note that if the first two entries were HH or TT, then it would finish in two throws. So, the probability is $\frac18 + \frac18 = \frac14$. The total probability is thus: $$\frac34$$

---

For the second part, the total probability is the sum of the probabilities of the events: game ends in three throws, in five throws, in seven throws, etc. Note that here, the last two throws should only be identical, the other throws should alternate (why?)

I will leave it to you with this hint.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first toss is $H$.
Then in order for the game *not* to end, the sequence of tosses must be
$$
HTHTHTHTHT\ldots.
$$
That means the chance to toss twice *without* ending the game is $\frac12$
(the first two tosses must be $HT$ or $TH$).
The chance to toss three times without ending the game is $\frac14.$
For $4$ times, it is $\frac18,$ and so forth.
Each time we increase the number of tosses by one, the probability is halved.

That means the chance to end on the second toss is $1 - \frac12 = \frac12,$ on the third toss is $\frac12 - \frac14 = \frac14,$ on the fourth toss is $\frac14 - \frac18 = \frac18,$ and so forth.
That is, the game ends on toss number $N$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}.$

The answer to the first question is a simple sum, and the answer to the second question is the sum of an infinite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gathered}
i) \ \ \ \ \ \underline{HH} H\ \ \underline{HH} T\ \ HTH\ \ H\underline{TT} \ \ T\underline{HH} \ \ THT\ \ \underline{TT} H\ \ \underline{TT} T\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \  >of\ the\ 8\ possibilities\ 6\ satisfy\ the\ condition\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ so\ \ P\ =\ 6/8\ =\ 3/4\ \ ( 75\%)\\
\\
ii) \ \ P\ =\ \frac{\#\ of\ rolls\ Joe\ can\ win}{\#\ of\ rolls} \ =\ \frac{n}{2n+1} \ \ \ \ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ a) \ If\ Joe\ wins\ on\ the\ third\ roll\ then\ P\ =\ \frac{n}{2n+1} \ =\ \frac{1}{3}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ b) \ If\ you\ assume\ Joe\ goes\ on\ forever\ then\ his\ P\ =\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \ \frac{n}{2n+1} \ =\ \frac{1}{2}
\end{gathered}

Comment: So you’re saying in (i) that the game will always end within three tosses? That’s obviously false.

Comment: Probability is not a sure thing. The probability of throwing a coin two separate times and getting heads one time is 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you quite understand what those numbers you’re producing mean. A probability of $1$ in this finite scenario means that the event *always* occurs. This should be a clue to you that you’ve made en error. The actual probability of getting exactly one head in two tosses is $1/2$: out of the four possible outcomes, two are “successes,” namely HT and TH.

Comment: You are correct - Thank you. I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i) $TT$, $HH$, $THH$, $HTT$. Sum of probabilities is $2 {1 \over 2^2} + 2 {1 \over 2^3}$.

ii) The probability of ending in $k$ throws, with $k \ge 2$ is
$2 {1 \over 2^k}$. Hence the probability of ending on an odd throw is
$2 ({1 \over 2^3} + {1 \over 2^5}+ \cdots) = {1 \over 3}$.